# SO Revision History GUI Representation

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is SO using a vendor available API to show edit history of posts? I have a mongodb setup which implements versioning of documents and I would like to emulate something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20387374/revisions

Comment: See also: [What is an Algorithm to Diff the Two Strings in the Same Way that SO Does on the Version Page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371474/what-is-an-algorithm-to-diff-the-two-strings-in-the-same-way-that-so-does-on-the)

Comment: Lol, after jumping around several posts, finally found this: http://www.horde.org/libraries/Horde_Text_Diff/download, looks like it is the way to go, as the xdiff library is no longer supported and hasn't been updated since 2008.

Comment: And that download link doesn't work, finally found it using this: ftp://ftp.tw.freebsd.org/pub/ports/distfiles/Horde/Horde_Text_Diff-2.0.1.tgz

Comment: And, that file requires Horde_String which isn't a stand-alone lib, rather it is bundled with Horde_Util, which can be downloaded here: http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/php-horde-Horde-Util/Horde_Util-2.2.0.tgz/